# How can I add data to an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel

I am trying to add several bills to a calendar I'm creating in Excel and cannot figure out how to add them line by line with the amount. Wrap text doesn't separate the bill and amounts how I need them; is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and expected output to be to give a better idea of what you want?

Comment: What do bills do in a calendar? Please post your data layout and explain in context.

Comment: Tried to improve the title, though I am guessing a bit what you want here!

Answer (score 0):

When typing in a cell in, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to force the text to start on a new line within the same cell.